# Global Hotkey/Shortcut Manager in WPF Prism (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism-4

How can I create a global hotkey binding in a wpf prism application, to which modules can add hotkeys dynamically ?

I tried the following:

Binding the `Window.InputCommands` to a `ObservableCollection` of my Hotkey class (using a
   common service as model)
    --> InputCommands does not contain a accessable setter

Working with the `PreviewKeyDownEvent` (EventToCommand)
    --> There are no solid ways to determine if Ctrl or Alt is pressed (out of doing it by 
    myself in the ViewModel). I don't like this approach.

Is there any easy way to Add key bindings dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to *easily dynamically* add/remove in pure MVVM. I'd want to access InputBindings from code-behind, as you duly noted the lack of a setter.  However, you may be inclined to break the design for this case only by looking into these two: [InputBindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.inputbindings.aspx) and [KeyGesture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keygesture.aspx). So consider creating a custom control for your shell.

```
    public ObservableCollection<HotkeyModel> Hotkeys { get; private set; }
    public class HotkeyWindow : Window
    {
        HotKeys = new ObservableCollection<HotkeyModel>();
        HotKeys.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(HotkeysChanged);
    }
    void HotkeysChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            foreach(HotkeyModel hk in e.NewItems)
                this.InputBindings.Add(new InputBinding(hk.Command), new KeyGesture(hk.Key, hk.Modifier));
        }
        else if(e. Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
            ...
    }
```

Don't set the InputBindings, instead you'd add and remove.  Keep that ObservableCollection of Hotkeys and listen for the [CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx) Event.  As they are added and removed, you add and remove from the InputBindings.  As you create a KeyGesture, you can set [Keyboard.Modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.modifiers.aspx).

So you could take this concept and extrapolate into a true and thorough MVVM design with attached/dependency properties and attached behaviors etc, to stick to the View and ViewModel separation that my above example ignores for now.

Comment: I Added a AttatchedProperty that takes a BindingCollection and reflects the changes to my Window.InputCommands collection.  Thank you for the suggestion.